# inherited list-style shortcode WordPress

Tags: wordpress, shortcode, inherited

I have set up tabbed content **(using Ultimatum framework and shortcode)** with text, images, and embedded YouTube videos. All works well, but I would like to know how to eliminate the bullet list style that is next to the tabbed menu. I think the class that calls this style is:

```
nav nav-tabs ult_tablinks
```

There is an issue of the main bullet styles that are in my custom css file which is:
Code:

```
/* Bullets */
.archive-page ul li,.entry-content ul li{list-style:squareoutsidenone;color:#421C52;}
/* Bullets End */
```

I like the way this setting styles the bullets throughout the site. Although, it is a problem in some areas like the styling in shortcode such as the tabs above because it is placing the bullets inside the tabbed menu.
The nav nav-tabs ult tablinks is inheriting the code below:
Code:

```
.archive-page ul li, .entry-content ul li {
list-style: square outside none;}
li {line-height: 20px;}
```

Is there anyway that I can still use the general bullet styling and just eliminate them from this shortcode area?

Here is the link to beta site where you can see what I am talking about. I would like the tabs to not reference a list-style.

http://www.drphyllisbooks.com/drbooks2014/books-neural-therapy/patient/

I am able to remove the bullets by deleting the **/* Bullets */** css above but then I don't have the nice bullet style throughout the site.

Any ideas on how I could fix this or better yet a solution would be greatly appreciated.

I thank you all for your time and consideration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this to your custom CSS file:

```
.entry-content ul.nav-tabs li { list-style:none; }
```

Appending "ul" with the .nav-tabs class specifies only the li's in the tabbed menu.

Comment: That did it!!  Thanks a lot and I will keep this for reference when learning and working with css.  Much appreciated!